# MySQL 8 ALGORITHM=INSTANT taking a long time

Tags: mysql, ddl, percona

I just ran the following `ALTER TABLE` statement with `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` on Percona Server for MySQL 8.0.33-25 and the statement took over 100 seconds to run: `ALTER TABLE documents ADD COLUMN test varchar(255), ALGORITHM=INSTANT;`.

During that time, my database was also unreachable from any other connection so I couldn't really check the processlist. As if all the connections were waiting.

This is a table with a good amount of traffic and over 300 000 000 rows. Yet, `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` should be a quick, non-locking operation and may only take a metadata lock breifly. In addition, based on MySQL's documentation, when a table or statement does not support `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` it should raise an error and not execute.

I read the MySQL documentation on the requirements for an `ADD COLUMN` with `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` and made sure my table was valid according to the requirements. I use `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` and have no `FULLTEXT` indexes.

**Edit**

Here is some additional information:
`SHOW CREATE TABLE documents;`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `documents` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `bucket` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `document_type` int DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `documentable_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `documentable_type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `file_size_bytes` int DEFAULT '0',
  `creator_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `theirs` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_documents_on_slug` (`slug`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_documents_on_documentable_user_id_created_at` (`documentable_type`,`documentable_id`,`user_id`,`created_at`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_documents_on_user_id_and_bucket_and_object_name` (`user_id`,`bucket`,`object_name`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_documents_on_creator_id` (`creator_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=452407889 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name = "documents";`

```
('documents', 'InnoDB', 10, 'Dynamic', 319689298, 357, 114200215552, 0, 109812432896, 24437063680, 452409978, '2023-07-12 19:03:23', '2023-07-17 11:48:21', NULL, 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', NULL, '', '')
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (yourtablename); so we have some idea of the effort involved by the Percona Server.  It would also be helpful for your to post TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKW ""yourtablename";  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck, of course! I just edit the initial post.

Comment: All info posted looks reasonable.  As suchislife suggested, time to open a ticket with Percona to see if they have a workaround available for you.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I opened a ticket with Percona, but still no update from them. I tested once more and managed to inspect the content of `show full processlist`. While the `ADD COLUMN` was running, it seems like all connections would hang with the state "Opening tables" until the `ADD COLUMN` completed.

Comment: It is likely this activity (Adding columns) should be done during your LEAST busy time of day.  If you have such a time.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: The B) attached is the same output as A).  We will need output of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS, please.  You can pick it up now and post, please.  No need to wait or redo any of the others.  Thank you for postings already available.

Comment: If you still have available the original SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; report, we could use that for our workload analysis.  Post to justpaste.it and share the link, please.

Comment: Thank you, workload analysis has started.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innob_open_files=8000  # from 400 to reduce opened_table RPS of 482     
table_open_cache=8000  # from 400 to match innodb_open_files (BEST PRACTICE) 
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 262144 to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 206,824
read_buffer_size=524288  # from 131072 to reduce Handler_read_next RPS of 882,751
```

Stop/Start of MySQL suggested for the changes to take effect.

There are many more opportunities to improve performance tuning.

Your ulimit report indicates Open Files is set on 1024.
To reduce delays when MySQL needs a table to be opened,
from OS command prompt,

```
ulimit -n 20000 and press Enter to raise the limit. A dynamic setting for OS.
```

After testing these changes, get in touch for tips on making
ulimit value persistent when rebooting server, please.

Table OPEN thrashing should be significantly reduced.

Comment: Philippe, Have you had an opportunity to try these suggestions?  Your conclusions?

Comment: sorry about the delay. We just tested out the new configurations you proposed. We had seen the same issues with a DROP TABLE for a table with over 2 000 000 000 rows. All processes were stuck in "Opening table" and the server crashed. With your new configurations, the table dropped in 0.14s! One addition I might add is that we needed to set `LimitNOFILE=20000` in `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf` to increase our `open_files_limit`. Thanks again!

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the feedback.  Please view profile.